# How do I Install lollypop in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, music-player

I recently discovered [Lollypop](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/lollypop), A GNOME music player, it looks awesome. How do I install it under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lollypop is a superb GNOME Music Player. It's been in the works for well over a year, and it already looks and works amazingly well.

[image]

#### Adding the PPA

---

[Lollypop](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/lollypop) supports more than one Linux distro. It supports five, plus FreeBSD. Supported versions: [ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/lollypop/), [Debian](https://launchpad.net/~gnumdk/+archive/ubuntu/lollypop), [Fedora](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/gnumdk/lollypop/), [Opensuse](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=home%3Agnumdk31&package=lollypop), [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~gnumdk/+archive/ubuntu/lollypop) (duh), [FreeBSD](https://www.freshports.org/audio/lollypop/).

Installing Lollypop is as easy as adding a PPA, refreshing your sources list, and installing the lollypop packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lollypop
```

The developer added some comment about getting Lollypop to work under 14.04.

> "Not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 (Do not handle an essential widget)" - [gnumdk (Cédric Bellegarde)](https://github.com/gnumdk), [Lollypop crashes under Ubuntu 14.04 · Issue #427 · gnumdk/lollypop](https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop/issues/427#issuecomment-174210344)

#### flathub

Lollypop is also available to install via flathub like so:

```
flatpak install flathub org.gnome.Lollypop
```

You can then search for it via your system application launcher, make sure the PPA version is removed, like so `apt remove lollypop`, otherwise you'll have 2 of the same applications.

Or you can run the app via the terminal

```
flatpak run org.gnome.Lollypop
```

#### Features

---

First, lets list all of the features:

- Artist bio, lyrics

  - Get artist biography from Wikipedia and Last.fm, read lyrics from Wikia
- Cover art downloader

  - Automatic artwork downloader from Last.fm, iTunes, Spotify
- Intuitive browsing

  - Walk through your collection by genres, artists and album artwork
- MTP devices

  - Sync your music with Android phones and any MTP devices
    -Search
- Search in your collection by artist, album and title. You can then play searched items, add them to the queue or to a playlist.
- Queue

  - The queue is a source designed to temporarily store the next tracks you want to play.
- Fullscreen view

  - Visual access from your couch
- Replay gain

  - Native replay gain support
- Party mode

  - Let Lollypop play music for you

---

### Compile

Just in case you want the latest and greatest, here is how to compile Lollypop under Ubuntu:

The following dependencies need to be satisfied before you can compile Lollypop:

```
gtk3
gobject-introspection
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 (Debian)
python3
intltool (make)
itstool (make)
totem-plparser
python (make)
python-cairo
python-dbus
python-gobject
python-sqlite
python-pylast >= 1.0
```

Here are some of the packages for debian based distros: `sudo apt-get install autoconf libglib2.0-dev intltool yelp-tools libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev`

```
git clone https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop.git
cd lollypop
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Regarding compiling Lollypop on Ubuntu 14.04 the developer, said:

> "Not compatible. Wait for next LTS" - [gnumdk (Cédric Bellegarde)](https://github.com/gnumdk), [Compile error: syntax error near unexpected token `disable-static · Issue #428 · gnumdk/lollypop](https://github.com/gnumdk/lollypop/issues/428#issuecomment-174210321)

Reference:

---

For more screenshots and information, see:

- [Lollypop, a GNOME Music Player - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/lollypop-a-gnome-music-player.php)

(I am the author)

Comment: Why is it so hard to install this? Why not providing a simple deb file or AppImage? Just asking.

Answer (score 2):

Lollypop is completly free open source distribution.
Try to use command:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnumdk/lollypop


  sudo apt-get update
```

Then run:

```
  sudo apt-get install lollypop
```

Player is installed, search it from the Ubuntu search bar.

To remove lollypop run::

```
sudo apt-get remove lollypop
```